# Nautilus (Files) 3.18.2 show other partitions as other locations, not under home directory listings

Tags: gnome, nautilus

In order to be able to install evolution 3.18.2 to Ubuntu 15.10, I had to add the gnome3-team ppa and the gnome3-team staging ppa. As a result, Nautilus (Files) is version 3.18.2. This is a problem (versus older versions) is that other partitions show as other locations, not under home directory listings. Just about all my data are not in my home directory by design.
How can I fix it ?
[Nautilus (Files) 3.18.2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy1rK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to downgrade nautilus but a better solution is mounting that partition via `fstab` in a specific directory and then add that directory as a bookmark in nautilus. In order to do this, open the `fstab` file from this path: `/etc/fstab` and then add 3 lines to the end of `fstab` with a structure similar to this:

```
UUID=1A2345B678901234 /path/to/dir            ntfs    user,rw              0       0
```

You have to replace values in this line with `uuid` of your file system, directory which you want to mount the partition in, partition type, options, dump and pass. Then click on menu key in nautilus and add mount points as bookmarks to the sidebar of nautilus windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, but a feature. (Seriously, not a good one, i hate it too :-) )

A workaround for this is bookmarking your partitions so they appear in the list below "Other Locations"